# Oat starch to sugar conversion in oat milk

Tags: substitutions, food-science, sugar, oat-milk

I noticed recently that some commercial oat milks do not have added sweetener but rather say that their sugar content comes from oat starch which was converted to sugar.  Is there some reasonably gentle way one could replicate this with home-made oat milk?

Comment: Please define "gentle": Is using a chemical at room T° gentle?

Comment: Ideally I was thinking of avoiding chemicals which one would not generally find in a pantry.  In practice, "gentle" should probably be relative to what is actually possible though.

Comment: How about naturally occurring enzymes?  Does that work for you (will still not be in your pantry though, but your local pharmacist has it/can get it for you)

Comment: As in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amylase ? If that is the most gentle way. That Wikipedia page leads me to "malt", which is something I do not have any experience with but looks interesting.

Comment: No, but same family.  Would that be acceptable?

Comment: See this too: http://www.oatly.com/process/

Answer (score 3):

Based on Fabby's suggestion in the comments on the question: oats can be malted (ref: [Wikipedia: Malt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malt)], which produces the enzymes needed to convert starch into sugar.  I am still in the process of trying this out (and will probably edit this answer at a later time); adding some of the dried oat malt to freshly made oat milk should do the trick (ref: [Oatly's description of their production process](http://www.oatly.com/process/)).

Comment: Better then I would have suggested: +1 (I would have given you glucoamylase as an answer)

Comment: Great topic!
How's your progress so far?
Doing trial and error at home using amylase of barley and the oat itself, turned out to become acidic at 30°C/86°F for 12hrs.